# Whole UITableviewcell is highlighted instead of rounded view inside the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, swift4, xcode9

I was trying to achieve the rounded tableview cell effect, so I tried to mess with layoutSubviews in my custom cell class:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {        
    // Set the width of the cell
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width - 40, self.bounds.size.height)
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

I heard that it is not recommended to change the width of the cell itself, and that adding a UIView (called mainView in the code) to the cell and adding constraints + corner radius would do the job.

My custom cell class is now:

```
class customTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        mainView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        mainView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mainView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

and here are the relevant components to my ViewController that holds the mainTableView:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            mainTableView.rowHeight = 100
            mainTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            mainTableView.delegate = self
            mainTableView.dataSource = self
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = self.mainTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! customTableViewCell

            // note that indexPath.section is used rather than indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

            // add border and color

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
            //cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            cell.clipsToBounds = true

            return cell
        }
```

**My result is this:**

[screenshot of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XBxw.png)

As you can tell, the whole cell is highlighted and not just what is inside.

My remaining question is - Is there a way to make only the UIView inside the contentView of the cell to be highlighted instead of the whole cell? Or should I just not enable selection and highlighting.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 4.1**, in your *tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt...)* or Storyboard tableview cell scene:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

in your cell subclass:

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
     // do your custom things with the cell subviews here
     if highlighted == true {
         self.contentView.backgroundColor = .gray
     } else {
         self.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desire effect. You just have to follow these steps.

Step 1 - Set your tableview cell's selection style to **UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Step 2 - In your **customTableViewCell**, override the default implementation of **setHighlighted(_:animated:)** and decide what you are going to highlight.

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // Change this to any color you want. 
}
```

You can also highlight individual elements of your custom UITableViewCell in this method.
I hope this helps.